# How to take text imported into Python and create a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, pdfminer

Hello (apologies in advance, new to programming and trying my best)

My aim is to convert a pdf to CSV.

I've imported a pdf document into Python using PDFMiner, which pastes all the text from within the PDF into Python. Is there a simple way to create a CSV file, with the imported text? Whats the best way to get this data out of Python in a different format?

The code I have used to import the PDF is Below:

```
import io
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                  caching=True,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)
        
    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
     # close open handles
     converter.close()
     fake_file_handle.close()

     if text:
    return text
if __name__ == '__main__':
print(extract_text_from_pdf(r'C:\Users\Matt\Documents\PDF Miner\sample.pdf'))
```

The output looks like this:

[example PDF in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz53X.jpg)

Thanks very much for any advise.

Comment: Why do you want to export in CSV format rather than just a plain text file? There are many Q&As here on SO that explain how to write out CSV from Python.

Comment: It's for processes within my job. A big part is taking text data from PDF documents (information on archival collections at museum etc) and saving this within our own spreadsheet template. My thought was an automated way of putting the data into a csv so this can be copy and pasted in bulk into our spreadsheet template, rather than slowing pasting from PDF document. Is PDF Miner not the best method? thanks

Comment: This sounds like you would like to keep the structure of the PDF (which may have a table-like layout?) and transfer different parts of the text extracted from one PDF file into different spreadsheet cells rather than just pasting all text into one cell? If so, I'd suggest to rephrase your question to focus less on the CSV export and more on the "how to extract a table from a PDF" aspect. (Exporting to CSV is then very likely the trivial part.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a good way to save in CSV
but
You can separate the text based on a character, for example. Or, save it to a CSV file later

```
import csv

text=extract_text_from_pdf(r'C:\Users\Matt\Documents\PDF Miner\sample.pdf').split(",")
writer=csv.writer(open("file.csv","w"))
writer.writerow(text)
```